# Can I ask about finding installers and drivers

Tags: discussion

If you're looking to find software drivers for a piece of physical device have the details of the device but don't know where to locate the software or a suitable alternative can you ask that device.

> e.g. I'm looking for the driver software for a Maginon Audio USB
>   Cassette converter to MP3Files Model number: ACC-001

Would the above be on or off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for asking.  It would be considered off topic because we recommend software based on requirements, not where to find it.

In your situation, you know exactly what you need, but not where to find it.

I spent a couple minutes looking for the driver you need, but I didn't find it either.

I don't believe there is a StackExchange site on which your question is on-topic.  Perhaps someone in one of the chat rooms might be able to help, or perhaps someone might be able to post a comment below as to a resource that might be able to help.

In any case, I wish you the best in finding the driver you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should distinguish between two things:

- Asking for *any* driver that can perform a certain operation with the given hardware: OK. Answers should include a link.
- Asking *where to download* the official driver made by the hardware manufacture: Not OK